# Most efficient way to convert str to int and back in python?

Tags: python

This works, but I feel it's not efficient to define a new variable just for a print call. IS there a better method to take an input and print it as a string. Then convert it to an int and possibly back yet again to a str?  I read up on the % command but don't believe I'm incorporating it correctly.

## Number test for if and block manuvering.

```
print ('This is a program to choose two numbers adding up to ten')
firstInput = input(" Pick a number? ")
firstNumber = int (firstInput)

print ('Ok the base number is ' + firstInput + ' so make that 10')

newNumber = int(input(' Number to add? '))


if newNumber + firstNumber == 5 + 5:
    print ("That worked!")

if newNumber + firstNumber != 5 + 5:
    print ("That didn't work!")`
```

Comment: Your code hardly has to worry about efficiency. Have you looked at string formatting yet?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  With the efficiency just want to pick up good habits as I learn.  I've seen a bit about string formatting (what I'm working on now really) But the {} is new to me.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) to interpolate integers:

```
print('Ok the base number is {} so make that 10'.format(firstNumber))
```

You can do much more complex formatting, but in this basic example the value for the first slot (`{}`) is taken from the first argument (`firstNumber`), which automatically is converted to a string with the `str()` built-in function.

As a complete program, with a few small optimizations:

```
print ('This is a program to choose two numbers adding up to ten')
firstNumber = int(input(" Pick a number? "))

print('Ok the base number is {} so make that 10'.format(firstNumber))

newNumber = int(input(' Number to add? '))

if newNumber + firstNumber == 10:
    print("That worked!")
else:
    print("That didn't work!")`
```